# JavaFX : How to progressively display multiple images after being loaded

Tags: java, image, javafx

I am creating a JavaFX application that loads multiple images from the internet (about 50)

The problem is that when I load all the images (with a thread), it displays them all at once which slows down the process.

I would like to display the images one by one when they have finished loading instead of displaying all at once **(like [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/)).**

I have been looking for a solution to this question for several days but I have not found anything...

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just load them in the [background](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,boolean))

Answer (score 3):

Load the image in the [background](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,boolean)), by setting the `backgroundLoading` parameter to `true`:

```
ImageView view = new ImageView(
    new Image(url, true)
);
```

The ImageView will automatically display the image when it has completed loading.

From the [Image](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) javadoc:

> ```
> // load an image in background, displaying a placeholder while it's loading
> // (assuming there's an ImageView node somewhere displaying this image)
> // The image is located in default package of the classpath
> Image image1 = new Image("/flower.png", true);
> ```